# How to get url alias of a link, when rewriting field output in Views

Tags: 7, views, tokens, path-aliases

I have an image field in Views, for which I must use "Rewrite output" option. The output of the image field is this:

```
<a href="/taxonomy/term/[tid]" title="Album &quot;[name]&quot;" class="vignette-wrapper">
[field_image]<span class="vignette"></span></a>
```

So, it contains a link to taxonomy term. But I would like this link to be the custom url for this taxonomy term, instead of raw Drupal path. My Pathauto pattern for taxonomy term is:

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]
```

But in Views, the `[term:parents:join-path]` token is not visible on the list of Replacement Patterns.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious, does the `/taxonomy/term/[tid]` URL not automatically redirect to your pathauto determined alias?  I know that's not ideal compared to serving the pathauto version.

Comment: Nope. Should it? When I type raw Drupal path in the browser directly, it also stays this way. I think custom path works when using php functions like l() or url(), but maybe I am missing some settings

Comment: Ah, I've got http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect enabled, which does do this.  So, there's one, less good potential solution.  

You could also look into `hook_views_pre_render()` to strongarm it.  Not sure exactly what that would look like, but maybe something along the lines of changing `$view->field['FIELDNAME']->options['alter']['path']`

Comment: The global redirect module solves this problem (and some others, too). So I would like to accept it as answer, could you please create an answer? I didn't succeed using hook_views_pre_render(), but discovered along the way that a field template override (as in Advanced->Theme section of view definition) gives access to those field values, so it's another possibility to keep in mind. But theming fields may affect performance and requires extra code. I'll actually use the global redirect module.

Comment: Cool, glad that will work for you. Theming the field is another possible solution too, though some might argue that you shouldn't put content changes in a tpl. As for performance, I can't really speak on that, but Drupal's pretty good at caching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Global Redirects module (drupal.org/project/globalredirect) would be one potential solution! It will automatically redirect all links on your site that are like that globally.

Answer (score 0):

I put

```
function [theme-name]_preprocess_views_view_field__[view-name]__tid(&$vars) {
  $vars['output'] = drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $vars['output']);
}
```

in `template.php` after adding the 'TID' field to the View. This also needs a copy of views-view-field.tpl.php, renamed according to the Theme Information provided by the View, in the theme folder in order to invoke the pre-process hook.